# Ruby: each line in different column

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv, text

I am a newcomer in Ruby and I have the following code:

```
out_file = File.open('new1.csv', 'w')
File.open("new7.txt").each do |line| 
  if line =~ /Revision/ then
    out_file.puts line
  elsif
    line =~ /Author/ then
    out_file.puts line
  elsif
    line =~ /Date/ then
    out_file.puts line
  end
end
```

I need:

- The line with "Revision" put in column A in the output CSV file
- The line with "Author" put in column B
- The line with "Date" put in column C
- And so on

Can anyone show me how to put the data in columns as described?

Right now all lines are put in one row.

The sample of "new7.txt"

```
Revision: 37407
Author: imakarov
Date: 21 June 2013 г. 10:23:28
Message:
update specification from Jhon (it was in VTBSOATST-1219)
----
Added : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5610/2 Спецификации/BR-5610 Публикация клиентских данных в АБС Бисквит (CifOraSyncOffPers).docx
Deleted : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5610/2 Спецификации/BR-5610 Публикация клиентских данных в АБС Бисквит.docx

Revision: 37406
Author: imakarov
Date: 21 June 2013 г. 10:22:16
Message: 
delete files

----
Deleted : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5610/2 Спецификации/ЧТЗ Принудительное обновление и публикация ФЛ с замечаниями Кочебина С..docx
Deleted : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5610/2 Спецификации/ЧТЗ Принудительное обновление и публикация ФЛ-comments.docx
Deleted : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5610/2 Спецификации/ЧТЗ Принудительное обновление и публикация ФЛ-comments_Орлов.docx
Deleted : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5610/2 Спецификации/ЧТЗ Принудительное обновление и публикация ФЛ.docx

Revision: 37405
Author: dboytsov
Date: 21 June 2013 г. 10:21:17
Message:
add attributes in file
----
Modified : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5864 Запрос данных клиента по интернет-анкете КН/Преобразование BR-5864.docx
Modified : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5864 Запрос данных клиента по интернет-анкете КН/ЧТЗ BR-5864 Запрос данных клиента по интернет анкете.docx
```

May be it would be a better way to export in .xls ?
Is it a difficult to export in .xls file in each column inside?

Now I have the following situation:
[image]

But I need that:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a sample of your source file ('new7.txt')?

Comment: Without a sample of your input file, we can only guess about what you need. That's not going to do you any good and will waste our time.

Comment: @the Tin Man I am sorry. Now I Update post.Add sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information provided by the OP,

```
require 'csv'

data = []
File.foreach("new7.txt") do |line|
  line.chomp!
  if line =~ /Revision/
    data.push [line]
  elsif line =~ /Author/
    if data.last and not data.last[1]
      data.last[1] = line
    else
      data.push [nil, line]
    end
  elsif line =~ /Date/
    if data.last and not data.last[2]
      data.last[2] = line
    else
      data.push [nil, nil, line]
    end
  end
end

CSV.open('new1.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  data.each do |record|
    csv << record
  end
end
```

- Should work well for lines in sequence: Revision, Author, Date, Revision, Date, Author, Revision, ...
- If lines are not well ordered:

  - `Revision` line is considered as the start of a new record
  - If there isn't a `Revision` line between 2 `Author` (or `Date`) line, the second `Author` (or `Date`) line is considered to be in a new record.

Comment: thank you a lot! I've tried, but now it puts all in one row. But I need to puts in every column seperately.

Comment: @DmitryBoytsov I've replaced `File.open` to `CSV.open` when writing the CSV file. Each record will be written in one line separately, rather than all joined in a single line.

Comment: I've checked with the sample data you provided, it should work as desired. Note that you need to store the data in a CSV file with the csv library, as the code I wrote.

Comment: Ok,I've tried again :) but what if I don't need to join in a single line?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `csv` library. Assuming that `new7.txt` has the column order of Author, Revision, Date, you can do the following:

```
require 'csv'

# parse the csv file into an array

CSV.parse("new7.txt", {:headers => false}).each do |line|

  # assign each 'cell' to a variable

  auther = line[0]
  revision = line[1]
  date = line[2]

  # append the newly order data onto a new csv file

  CSV.open("new7_revised.txt", "a") do |csv|
    csv << [revision, author, date]
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the question, where the input data in `new7.txt` isn't in the CSV format. Some lines contain "Revision", some lines contain "Author", etc.

Comment: Ah, I thought that the OP wanted the columns to be reordered.

Comment: @DarshanComputing
Yes, you are absolutelu right. The input 'new7.txt' file is not a csv, it's just a txt. And Inside it I have such words as "Revision" "Author" "date" and so on. In input file it is not a column. And I want to parse the input file and copy to csv by columns